# Value tuples exist, so why use the "out" parameter modifier?

Tags: c#, out, valuetuple

[Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier#declaring-out-parameters) for the `out` parameter modifier points out the following:

> Declaring a method with `out` arguments is a classic workaround to return multiple values. Consider value tuples for similar scenarios.

This strikes me as a remarkably good point. What use case remains for `out`, now that we have value tuples?

Comment: The `TryDoSomething` pattern (returns Boolean true on success, with the output in an`out` parameter) relies on it. It's been around since day 1 (I think `double.TryParse` was in v1.0 of the Framework)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning two values, Tuple vs 'out' vs 'struct'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381918/returning-two-values-tuple-vs-out-vs-struct)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One major use case I can think of off the top of my head are `Try...` methods that return a value and a boolean so that you can check whether the action succeded or not:

```cs
// With out parameters:
if(int.TryParse(someString, out int result)){
   // do something with the int
}

// With tuples:
var (success, value) = int.TryParseWithTuples(someString);
if(success){
   // do something with the int
}
```

With the `out` parameter, the notation is cleaner and results in less lines (and doesn't require you to create a local variable for the success boolean). It also allows you to do this:

```cs
if(int.TryParse(someString, out int r1)){
   // do something with the int
} else if(int.TryParse(fallbackString, out int r2)){
   // do something with the fallback int
} else {
   throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

With tuples, this would look like this:

```
var (success, value) = int.TryParseWithTuples(someString);
if(success){
   // do something with the int
} else {
   (success, value) = int.TryParseWithTuples(fallbackString);
   if(success){
       // do something with the fallback int
   } else {
       throw new InvalidOperationException();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the ease of use of the `TryX` pattern, as pointed out by [ascpixi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74083049/11178549), another case that makes a value-tuple unsuitable as a return type is when one of the two values is a reference. For example take a look at the [`CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal.getvaluereforadddefault) API:

```
public static ref TValue? GetValueRefOrAddDefault<TKey,TValue> (
    Dictionary<TKey,TValue> dictionary,
    TKey key,
    out bool exists);
```

It is used like this:

```
ref int refValue = ref CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault(
    dictionary, key, out bool exists);

if (!exists) refValue = 1; else refValue++;
```

The [`ValueTuple<T1, T2>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple-2) is not a [`ref struct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/ref-struct), so it could not be used for this API. Theoretically this API could return a custom tuple-like `ref struct`, but in that case it would lack the language support that exists only for real value-tuples, like the shorthand notation with parentheses etc.

Answer (score 0):

As a semi-escoteric case, there may be cases where the size of a tuple may have different passing semantics compared to an `out`. [Sharplab shows different ASM for out vs ValueTuple](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBDAzgWwB8ABAJgEYBYAKGIGYACMhgYQYG8aHunGAKADYQAdgHMG2NAyFiGwAJQMAsgBkRogCoBXAA4CYfRZ2o9TTAOwM+5NKXkBuLjwC+T7vWnrlasQHktGHwQAZ6yCm4cEabADAC8DKSOJmbuluRJpq7J7vwAlsIYElL5hQrKAJIF2noGRlE8xJbWtg4RWaYeJRUF/oHBhV3h2ZHD0XEJGSkWDOltNM5AA) which tends me towards thinking there are performance-sensitive cases where `out` would be better.

Another case that comes to mind, before 'named tuples' became a thing, was that the signature with `out` args could be more descriptive as to the values.

As the docs suggest, normally modern, 'named' ValueTuples are very composable and often great for app-level behavior. But for the reasons mentioned above, it was easier to make compiler sugar around some constructs for transition's sake.