# Creating dictionary with potentially nullable generic key type

Tags: c#, dictionary, nullable, nullable-reference-types

I'm writing up a generic method that needs to internally use a `Dictionary` keyed by the generic parameter.

I don't want to impose any constraint on the generic parameter itself, in particular no [`notnull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint) constraint. However, the method would be capable of handling nulls explicitly, and of course not adding any null keys to the dictionary it's using.

Is there any best practice for doing so?

By default, the compiler warns that the generic key type doesn't match the `notnull` constraint of `Dictionary<,>`.

See an example below. Unless I'm missing something, this should be perfectly safe. But how can I best convey this to the compiler? Is there any way other than suppressing the compiler warning here?

```
public static int CountMostFrequentItemOrItems<T>(params T[] values)
{
    var counts = new Dictionary<T, int>();  // The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'TKey' in the generic type or method 'Dictionary<TKey, TValue>'
    var nullCount = 0;
    
    foreach(var value in values)
        if (value is null)
            ++nullCount;
        else if (counts.TryGetValue(value, out var count))
            counts[value] = count+1;
        else
            counts[value] = 1;

    // ... combine results etc ...
}
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632945/why-doesnt-dictionarytkey-tvalue-support-null-key

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't Dictionary<TKey, TValue> support null key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632945/why-doesnt-dictionarytkey-tvalue-support-null-key)

Comment: @CthenB Neither of those answer the question. OP knows that dictionaries don't support null keys -- the question is very clear on this. The question is about now to structure NRT annotations to tell the compiler that even though `T` is nullable, the dictionary will never be given a null key

Comment: I'm not even sure whether it's possible to suppress this...

Comment: @canton7 I think suppressing by "#pragma warning disable/restore CS8714" works .. but is a little ugly!

Comment: @canton7 the linked post has a most-upvoted answer showing how to bypass the issue by creating a custom implementation which handles the null separately.

Comment: As a side note, the `CountMostFrequentItemOrItems` method could be optimized with the [`CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal.getvaluereforadddefault) API ([usage example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74083010/value-tuples-exist-so-why-use-the-out-parameter-modifier/74083392#74083392)).

Comment: @CthenB That describes how do create a new type to use as the key, which effectively hacks in support for null keys. That is one potential workaround, but it doesn't directly answer the question

Comment: Maybe not topic of that question, but I wouldn't solve this problem with a `Dictionary<>` at all. I would use `GroupBy` to group, then `Where` to remove any null, and then a `Max` in combination with `Count` to get the most frequent item. Should be a oneliner.

Comment: @MatthiasAuswöger the `GroupBy` is an inefficient solution for this problem. What you need is the [`CountBy`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/77716), which is currently just a proposal.

Comment: It's worth noting that MoreLinq's implementation of CountBy doesn't support null keys

Comment: Dictionary has a constraint `where TKey : notnull`, so if you can bypass it, you also break the c# constraints.

Comment: I only get the warning when project has `<nullable>enable</nullable>`

Comment: @Magnus Yeah, that's the default now for .Net 7/C#11 (for new projects)

Comment: How does the full function look?

Comment: The "proper" solution would be to support some variation of `MaybeNull`/`NotNull` on the type parameter itself (so *not* as a constraint), as that's the usual way to work around situations where you know better than the compiler, but .NET doesn't currently offer this (support for attributes on type parameters was added at some point, though, so this *could* be done). Suppressing the warning is the correct approach here -- that's why nullability analysis is warnings in the first place, since we *know* the compiler can't do this perfectly with the approach C# has chosen.

Comment: Yep totally agree with Jeroen - just suppress the warning.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert . I wasn't sure if I missed anything, but looks like that's unfortunately not the case. Feel free to post this as the answer to this question then; an ugly solution is still better than no solution!

Comment: The ability to write `new Dictionary<T!, int>()` would be yet another "proper" solution.